# How can I Display both checkin and checkout time in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the checkout time and check in time to display in a html/php table.  Currently,
I can view either the check in time or the checkout time  but not both in tables.  This is the code that I am using:

`$ListQuery = "SELECT * FROM systemlogs WHERE ((itembarcode='".@$_POST["inputdata"]."') and (action='checkinitem')) ORDER BY actiondatetime DESC";`

The part (action='checkinitem') let me view only the checkin time but if I change it to (action='checkoutitem') then I can view only the checkout time.  How can I view both checkinitem and checkoutitem.

MySQL Tables

```
actiondatetime                          |                       action
 2013-03-22   5:00 pm                                           checkin
 2013-03-22   8:00 pm                                           checkout
```

---

I would like to View in web page table:

```
Checkout                                  |                     Checkin
2013-03-22   5:00 pm                                 2013-03-22  8:00pm
```

Comment: To get the desired results you have to tie a checkout time to its corresponding checkin time. What value relates the two times? Put another way: in a table with thousands of checkout/checkin times, what tells you that two of those times belong together on the same rows in your web page table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

`WHERE action IN ('checkouttime', 'checkintime')`

Comment: Where in my code would I place this: WHERE action IN ('checkouttime', 'checkintime')

Comment: $ListQuery = "SELECT * FROM systemlogs WHERE ((itembarcode='".@$_POST["inputdata"]."') and (action IN ('checkouttime', 'checkintime'))) ORDER BY actiondatetime DESC";